# How to get outer column value in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am Implementing a Social networking website using php and mysql and I am stuck with a query to get notification.

My **notification** table has these columns:

> user_id,post_id,type(*defines weather its a comment(value 2) or a
>   post(1)*),
>
> status(*0 read 1 not read*),msg(for optional message)

**comments** table:

> comment_id ,  user_id ,   post_id, comment ,  time ,  status

**like** table:

> **user_id** ,    **post_id**(can store either post_id from post table or
>   comment_id from comment table) ,  **type**(*same as type of notification*) 
>   *all three columns makes a unique combo*

now I want to get the notification output like:

> notification_id    |     message
>
> 1    |  3 peoples Liked your post
>
> 2     |   2 peoples Commented on your post

I created this query

```
SELECT `notification_id`,
    CASE 
    WHEN `msg` IS NOT NULL THEN msg
    WHEN `type`=1 THEN concat((SELECT count(user_id) from `likes` WHERE `post_id`=post_id AND `type`=1 AND `user_id`!='8'),' peoples Liked your post')
    WHEN `type`=2 THEN concat((SELECT count(*) from (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id`=post_id AND `user_id`!='8') AS commenters),' peoples Commented on your post')
    END AS message
FROM
    `notifications` WHERE `user_id`='8' -- 8 is just a user_id I was testing on.
```

it seems to be working fine until I realized the values were incorrect and I soon realized my mistake was in

```
`post_id`=post_id
```

which is true all the time so all of the rows are counted.

I searched for getting outer column value but couldn't find a solution ,Can you please help me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use aliases in your query.. the `FROM` alias issue is most likely from your Comments Count subquery.. which you can rewrite as `Select count(distinct user_id)`

```
SELECT n.notification_id,
    CASE 
    WHEN n.msg IS NOT NULL THEN n.msg
    WHEN type=1 THEN concat((SELECT count(user_id) from likes AS l WHERE l.post_id=n.post_id AND l.type=1 AND l.user_id != n.user_id),' peoples Liked your post')
    WHEN type=2 THEN concat((SELECT count(DISTINCT c.user_id) FROM comments AS c WHERE c.post_id=n.post_id AND c.USER_ID != n.user_id),' peoples Commented on your post')
    END AS message
FROM
    notifications AS n 
WHERE 
    n.user_id='8' -- 8 is just a user_id I was testing on.
```

here is a working sql fiddle example [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5730e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an ALIAS name for your table.

For example:

```
FROM Notifications AS N
```

In this case you give an alias name to the Notifications table. In that way you can refer to columns of Notifications table by using N.any_column_of_notifications_table.

With this concept you can access outer values, for example:

```
SELECT x.id, y.id
    FROM Table_1 AS x,
    INNER JOIN Tabel_2 AS y
WHERE x.user_id = y.user_id
```

For more: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: I am sorry but alias won't do in this case.